# Why not immediately copy and circulate Utopia Part 2?

Tags: utopia

In the TV series, "Utopia", the Utopia Manuscript is a long-lost second part to a comic book. Some very powerful people want to keep it under wraps (unpublished, unknown to the public), and the protagonists spend forever running around with the thing, avoiding the bad guys etc.

My fridge thought after finishing the first season is: why didn't the characters immediately scan and widely publish Utopia pt. 2, for all to read? This seemed to be the main outcome that the bad guys were trying to avoid, and the characters had ample time and access to the Internet to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first series begins with one of the group of comic book aficionados acquiring the Utopia manuscript and then being murdered by the Network before being able to pass it on to the others. However, another of the group, Grant, is unexpectedly present when this happens and is able to get away with the manuscript and meet up with the other members of the group.

The Network immediately goes after the remaining members of the group, framing them for serious crimes to discredit them. The only leverage the group has against the Network is that they possess the manuscript, or know the location of it. Even if you assume that they had the opportunity to scan the manuscript and distribute it, they wouldn't have done this as **it would have removed the only reason the Network had to not kill them on sight** (as they did with everyone else that had even a passing knowledge of the related events).